# Cloned my hard drive to SSD but not Windows 10 is not booting up

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

I used [easeus clone software](https://www.easeus.com/backup-software/tb-free.html) to clone my hard drive to SSD(Samsung 1 TB SSD). The clone process took good amount of time(more than 4 hours) as i think it has lot to clone.

After that when i put the new SSD and removed the old hard drive - I am getting some weird errors.
Like [image: this]:
your pc/device needs to be repaired a required device isn't connected or can't be accessed 
Error code 0xc0000225

Yes, the same one is being mentioned at this link by the tools guys [also](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/a-required-device-is-not-connected-or-cannot-be-accessed.html)

But i have a complex situation. Mine is a dual boot Ubuntu Linux system with GRUB as a boot loader. I don't know what all is being messed up?
Anybody else faced the same issue? What could be the possible fix?

Another update:
After booting from the Windows boot drive(USB) made following this(go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=616447) - i found that C: doesn't have anything and the D: drive which was having Windows has got everything. What to do? On command prompt X drive - it says that command not found when trying bootrec /fixMbr

Comment: Did you clone the entire drive (every partition) as is to the SSD? Did you make any changes in the BIOS?

Comment: After booting from the Windows boot drive(USB) made following this(http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=616447) - i found that C: doesn't have anything and the D: drive which was having Windows has got everything. What to do? On command prompt X drive - it says that command not found when trying bootrec /fixMbr

Comment: No there is no changes done in the BIOS by me but BIOS recognized the new SSD drive.

Comment: Maybe It is not correctly installed SSD, the boot order could be changed, or system partition issue. Here https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/cloned-ssd-wont-boot.html you can see how can you make SSD bootable

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this:
I cloned my Win 10 laptop to a new Crucial SSD, and used the cloning software that Crucial provide.
I was gutted to received the blue screen error on boot: 0xc0000225

My fix was:

1. Boot into Windows Recovery Environment using the Windows 10 installation media.
2. Click on Repair your computer.
3. Click on Troubleshoot and in the Advanced options.
4. Select Command Prompt. Type the following commands into the prompt and press Enter key after each command.

• bootrec /fixmbr

• bootrec /fixboot  <---  This gave an access denied.

• bootrec /scanos

The laptop booted straight after this!  :-D

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used the Samsung magician that can be downloaded from [here](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/). It worked like charm. In less than 40 minutes - the entire drive was cloned without any problems/issues. Sadly it only work with Samsung SSDs only.